# Structs: field must be fully assigned compiler error

Tags: c#, constructor, struct

I've declared the following struct:

```
struct StartPositions
{
    public Vector2 pacman;
    public Vector2[] ghosts;

    // Constructor accepts a Vector2, and an array of Vector2's.
    public StartPositions(Vector2 pacmanPosIn, Vector2[] ghostsPosIn)
    {
        pacman = pacmanPosIn;
        for(int a=0;a<ghostsPosIn.Length;a++)
        {
            ghosts[a] = ghostsPosIn[a];
        }
    }
}
```

However I get a compiler error saying the ghosts field must be fully assigned. What I want to do is pass in a Vector2, and a Vector2 array when I create a StartPositions object - making a copy of that array.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You forgot to allocate the array for `ghosts`.

Comment: Oh crikey tell me that's not true

Comment: You know that compiler error you got that said that ghosts was never assigned to?  It was correct.

Answer (score 2):

You did not initialize the `ghosts` array. You need to add a call to `new`.

```
public StartPositions(Vector2 pacmanPosIn, Vector2[] ghostsPosIn)
{
    pacman = pacmanPosIn;
    ghosts = new Vector2[ghostsPosIn.Length];
    ....
}
```

And you can simplify the code by replacing the `for` loop with a call to `Array.Copy()`.

```
Array.Copy(ghostsPosIn, ghosts, ghosts.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your `ghosts` array first:

```
struct StartPositions
{
    public Vector2 pacman;
    public Vector2[] ghosts;

    // Constructor accepts a Vector2, and an array of Vector2's.
    public StartPositions(Vector2 pacmanPosIn, Vector2[] ghostsPosIn)
    {
        pacman = pacmanPosIn;
        ghosts = new Vector2[ghostsPosIn.Length];
        for(int a=0;a<ghostsPosIn.Length;a++)
        {
            ghosts[a] = ghostsPosIn[a];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `ghosts` array.

```
public StartPositions(Vector2 pacmanPosIn, Vector2[] ghostsPosIn)
{
    ...
    ghosts = new Vector2[ghostsPosIn.Length];
    ...
}
```

From [*C# Language Specification*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx);

> Actual array instances are created dynamically at run-time using the
>   **new** operator. The new operation specifies the **length of the new array**
>   instance, which is then fixed for the lifetime of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

One annoying quirk in .net is that unless one is using "unsafe" code the concept of a value-type array does not exist.  The struct as shown contains a position for the "pacman" and a reference to a mutable array that holds the positions of the ghosts.  This is an evil combination, since the struct may appear to encapsulate the positions of the ghosts, but it does not.  Thus, if one were to say:

```
StartPositions p1 = whatever();
... do some stuff
StartPositions p2 = p1;
p2.pacman.X += 3;
p2.ghosts[0].X += 3;
```

the code would add three to `p2.pacman` and `p2.ghosts[0]`; it would not affect `p1.pacman.X` but *would* add three to `p1.ghosts[0]`.  Such behavior would likely cause confusion.

If your intention is that `StartPositions` will be read-only, it should probably never expose the `ghosts` array directly; instead, `ghosts` should be a property of type `IList<Vector2>`, and your constructor should set it to something like a new `ReadOnlyList<Vector2>` initialized with a copy of the passed-in positions.  If it does that, then `ghosts` can simply be a read-only property that returns such positions.